# NTFS Disk mounting

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs

How I can mount windows NTFS drive?

I am double clicking on drive icon. But showing no permission.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 6):

First you need to create directory where you can attach windows partition using mount command (for example `/media/c` for C:):

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/c
```

Now find out list of partition (click on System > Administration > Disks ) or use following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If  `/dev/hdb1` is NTFS partition. Now type following command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/hdb1 /media/c
```

To unmount Windows NTFS partition type command:

```
sudo umount /media/c
```

for reference [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 4):

There is a feature (?) called Fast Startup which is turned on by default in Windows 8, 8.1 & 10. It is a setting that helps your PC start up faster after shutdown. Windows does this by saving system info to a file (hiberfil.sys) upon shutdown.

Ubuntu detects this as a corrupt NTFS partition. Windows 7 also detects this as corrupt but repairs it making the file system accessible by Ubuntu.

You can fix this in Windows power options. Find the setting for what the power switch does and turn off fast startup (you may have to use advanced settings). I'm being vague because 8, 8.1 & 10 have different power setup windows and I don't have 8 or 8.1 to articulate a procedure.

After turning off the Fast Startup I could see the disk going from 10 straight to Ubuntu. I no longer have to let 7 repair the disk first.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

where `X` is the letter of the drive and `Y` the number of the partition.